Robert Rankin-esque comic fantasy book from the 90's in which TV equipment grows like plants (or possibly plants are TV equipment)
I remember reading a book when I was still at school (so before 1998), that was a comic-fantasy novel similar in style to Robert Rankin (possibly it is by Robert Rankin, but I can't figure out which book).
The premise was a bit inconsistent, but basically on an alien world, otherwise much like Earth, TV equipment grows like plants. So they develop TV in their culture really early, and their entire civilisation revolves around it. The premise seems to flip-flop (or I can't remember) whether it's electronic TV's growing out of the ground like plants, or plants that can act like TV cameras. (at one point a character is filmed in a shower by the mould growing on the wall).
I think a male human protagonist is somehow swept up in being sort of reality TV star (but this is before the phrase "reality TV" was commonplace, I think). His Sister is a TV executive and has to save him on occasion. I really can't remember much else about the plot.

There are biological cameras (using film!) in Varley's Demon, but that's clear not the book you're looking for.

If it's Robert Rankin, it's most likely to be his Armageddon trilogy.  I seem to recall a race of tv-obsessed aliens who basically caused events on earth, such as Armageddon, just so they have something to watch on television. From the first book, Armageddon: The Musical:


And so it was with the Phnaargs of Phnaargos. Their
'gotta doing' was not immediately apparent. They lived upon a gloriously verdant world, devoid of
killer reptiles and flying scorpions, rich in natural vegetation, with a mild climate and some
really knockout sunsets. However, to wax biblical, this Eden was not without its serpent. Only
here it came in the form of the cathode ray tube. Mankind didn't come across this miracle until
its closing moments, but it wasn't so on Phnaargos. For on Phnaargos, the cathode ray tube grew
wild. And so, at a time when humankind was still tossing rocks at the hairy elephants and
experimenting with DIY in the family cave, the Phnaargs were watching TV.
Now, if it was strange that the cathode ray tube should grow wild upon a planet, then it is surely
stranger still that the botanical equivalents of the video camera, the microphone, the mixing
desk, the spotlight, the little monocular thing that a really duff director wears around his neck,
and all the other paraphernalia necessary to television production, should similarly be blooming
away, ready for the harvest. In fact, many might be forgiven for finding it unlikely, to say the
very least. But the Almighty moves in mysterious ways, his wonders to perform. And who are we to
question his motives?
Now, with all this technology sprouting around them, one might also be forgiven for thinking that
the Phnaargs were a 'race blessed of God'. But, you'd be wrong on that one too. For nothing could
be further from the truth. The Phnaargs were the first race ever to become irrevocably hooked on
television, the first to fall victim to the dangerous and terminally addictive radiations of the
cathode ray tube. And once infected at such an early stage in their development, they were well
and truly done for.
Within a few short years of their discovery, the planet was literally forested with cultivated TV
stations and the
Phnaargs, almost slaves. Those not engaged in full time viewing strove to supply the needs of
those who were. The needs soon became demands and the demands were wild. For this was a young and
primitive stock and it liked its TV meaty!


Can you be more specific? As things stand this isn't much of an answer.

This sounds like it, though I can't find the scene in the shower. The protagonist's sister is Gloria Mundi, and she is a station controller.

I think this is it (I'll give it a read to be sure). The quoted passage sounds very familiar. Many thanks.

Ah cathode ray tubes. How quaint! :D
